# check expiry cards

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table to stores expiry dates of credit cards, below is the sample schema for table.

```
ExpiryDate Varchar(10)
```

Sample Data in Table is as follows:-

```
'08/10'
'09/11'
'08/16'
'10/17'
```

how can i find out if a card's date is expired?

Comment: I'm not really understanding what the question here is?  You want to know, from a string like '08/10', how do you translate that into some other representation of August 2010?

Comment: Can you change the table structure so you have a date instead of a string? Storing date information in strings like you have is a nightmare to deal with.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Show us what have you done and what is your expected result.

Comment: yes, i am trying get all accounts have expired ex:if the card number have expiry '07/15', then this means the card is expired and no longer valid ... the other way is , i am trying to find all active accounts/credit cards which have expiry greater than today or this month ..sorry for not posting the question clearly

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are expected, but You can use string manipulation with substring to get records those are not expired

```
Select *
FROM supportContacts
WHERE LEFT(ExpiryDate,2) >= MONTH(GETDATE()) AND RIGHT(ExpiryDate,2) >= RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()),2)
```

If you want expired card list then use this

```
Select *
FROM supportContacts
WHERE LEFT(ExpiryDate,2) < MONTH(GETDATE()) AND RIGHT(ExpiryDate,2) <= RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()),2)
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3b78d/1)

Comment: @Nick - really?  It looks to me like it would pull accounts that have not expired yet.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
select * from BillingInfo
where 
    cast(left(expiryDate, 2) as int) --take the month portion of the expiry date
    < select datepart(mm, getdate()) --expiry month must be before current month
and
    cast(right(expiryDate, 2) as int) --take the year portion of the expiry date
    <= select datepart(yy, getdate()) % 1000 --expiry year must also be during or before current year
```

The `% 1000` converts the year to two-digit format.

Comment: `%1000` returns 1 digit if the year were between 2000 and 2009 including.

Comment: Good point - I have edited to convert the varchars to ints, although I think generally it will not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from billinginfo 
where substring(expirydate,1,charindex('/',expirydate)-1) < month(getdate())
and '20'+ substring(expirydate,charindex('/',expirydate)+1, 2) <= year(getdate())
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

With such an awful data structure you are forced to kludge this together. Here is one way of doing it.

```
with BadData as
(
    select '08/10' as SemiDate union all
    select '09/11' union all
    select '08/16' union all
    select '10/17'
)

select *
from BadData
where cast(replace(STUFF(SemiDate, 4, 0, '01-20'), '/', '-') as DATE) < CAST(getdate() as DATE)
```

If you stored the ExpirationDate as a date instead of a string this would be simple. I sure hope you aren't storing the credit card number alongside this.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want this:

```
 SELECT TOP 4 * 
 FROM BillingInfo
 WHERE ExpiryDate in ('08/10','09/11','08/16','10/17')
```

This will find you the 4 items with those dates.

Comment: nope, i was trying to find out the cards which have expired using the expiry date..

Comment: so you want to know how to translate a date formatted as this type of string into a date to compare against GETDATE()?

Comment: If this is the case tell me so.  But don't downvote my answer when your question was not clear.  I have NO interest in helping you solve this problem now.

Comment: I doubt the OP downvoted you, considering their rep.

Comment: @APH - whatever I edited his question so he got good answers, my work here is done.